# Regex to split years, months, and weeks

Tags: php, regex

Given a string like this:

"7 years 11 months 3 weeks"

I need to parse it out so that in PHP, the preg_split function returns an array that contains:

```
0 => "7 years"
1 => "11 months"
2 => "3 weeks"
```

The age string can also contain zeros like `"0 years 1 month 0 weeks"`.

The regex string I have right now only seems to split between years and months:

`(?!\d+)(?:\s)(?!\D+)`

and that is throwing off the calculations.

I'm not very familiar with regex and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? DateInterval::createFromDateString gives you the result of such strings in years, months and days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_match_all('~\d+\s+\w+~', $text, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HnCbKf/2).

Note that `preg_match_all` extracts all occurrences of pattern matches.

*Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\w+` - one or more letters/digits/underscores.

Other regex variations:

- `\d+\s+\S+` - the `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars, so it will match words with hyphens and any other special chars
- `\d*\.?\d+\s+\S+`  - `\d*\.?\d+` will match both integer and float values.

**NOTE**: To get the number and word as submatches capture them:

```php
preg_match_all('~(\d+)\s+(\w+)~', $text, $matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is

```php
$age = '7 years 11 months 3 weeks';

$result = preg_split('/ (?=\d)/', $age);

print_r($result);
```

Your regex is exactly equivalent to `\s(?!\D)` which should also work anyway, though if there was a space at the end of the string you would get an unwanted empty string result.